# Establishing a secure connection to a secured database in SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have just created a database secured with a symmetric key.

The question is, How can I access the database with a secure conncection from a standalone C# application created in .net 3.5 and SQL Server 2008 (as sql database is a part of application)

Just putting the the key inside the .exe file would be an unsecure way to access the data,or am I missing something?

Please provide specific guide as I am (almost) new to sql.
Thanks.

Update:*I mean, I have encrypted a table column with sensitive data to avoid data abuse.*

*And I want to write a c# code which automatically decrypt ,perform read or write actions on the data column and encrypt again.*

*The problem is, if I write the direct password inside the code,the whole implementation would be useless.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have just created a database secured with a symmetric key

What exactly did you do? There is no such thing as you describe. You may had created a symmetric key, but that is something completely different from 'securing' a database.

> How can I access the database with a secure connection

Use SSL. See [Encrypting Connections to SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx) for step-by-step instructions.

If you need more specific answer about SQL Server security and/or cryptography you will need to describe what are you trying to achieve. What are you trying to protect, and against what specific threat. You should also go over the [Encryption Hierachy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189586.aspx). As a general rule though, one can never embed a secret inside an application. Data encrypted by a key hierarchy derived form a password is decrypted by **asking the user for the password**.

Comment: Sorry for the bad english.I mean, I have encrypted a table column with sensitive data to avoid data abuse. And I want to write a c# code which automatically decrypt ,perform read or write actions on the data column and encrypt again. The problem is, if I write the direct password inside the code,the whole implementation would be useless. I you misunderstood the question again, feel free to comment or reply.

Comment: And for additional info,I would be appreciated if provided with an alternative way, e.g: a custom class declared inside the application which read/write sensitive data as string(and the custom class works like a table) and directly hard-coding that class into the application and encrypting the data storage.

Comment: _Remus said:As a general rule though, one can never embed a secret inside an application..._ too bad, thanks for the answer though

Comment: Ok I got it. While reading the encryption hierachy I have noticed the following method:EKM, I have searched for the word and found out: SQL Server 2008 Extensible Key Management enables the encryption keys that protect the database files to be stored in an off-box device such as a smartcard, USB device, or EKM/HSM module. Now that's what I was looking for; thanks for the help(links, useful data and etc.). (For the ones that are curious,I was looking for a way to access encrypted data without user interaction.)

Comment: You should also look at [Transparent Data Encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx). Both TDE and EKM are available only in SQL Server 2008 and later, and both require Enterprise Edition license.